# Is there a good reason to discourage .peek() in Stacks in Queues?

Tags: java

I am in an introductory CS (Java) class and the teacher does not allow us to use .peek() on our Queue's or Stack's.

Obviously on a stack this is a fairly easy workaround as we may have as many temporary ints as we want. One can simply pop the value off onto a variable and push it back on. This is likely the way it is implemented behind the scenes.

On a queue this makes things a bit more complicated however it still can be done. However I am not sure how java implements queue.peek so I cant speak to the peek replacement here.

Ultimately I am wondering. Why is it good practice to discourage peeking into Stacks and Queues?

Comment: Did he tells you not to use it for good practice or simply to find a solution to a specific problem ? Also, did you ask your teacher ? (seems the simpler way to get the answer)

Comment: @AxelH We are not allowed to use it at any point during the course.

Comment: A quick check of some of the standard queue implementations shows there's no significant cost involved. This may be different if you're talking about a queue more generally, such as `JMS`. First port of call for this would be your teacher, it's not a "rule" I've heard before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is it good practice to discourage peeking into Stacks and Queues?

Because:

1. Peeking is often associated with polling<sup>1</sup>, and polling is wasteful.
2. If you call `peek()` and then `pop()` or `remove()` in a multi-threaded application there is no guarantee that you will get the same element each time.

Now, clearly, not all uses of `peek()` are bad.  But these are reasons why it can be bad.

But I also agree with the people who suggested that you ask your teacher!

---

<sup>1 - ... polling in the sense of *repeatedly* looking at what is on the front of the queue, or testing if it is empty / non-empty.</sup>